# Checking which words in a list could be made from user input letters

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm trying to let users put in a list of letters separated by commas, and find out what words could be made from those letters. The program uses a list of words to compare against the input letters.

This is the code that I have tried. I have tried it several different ways, and this was my least unsuccessful trial.

```
#import list, get user input and separate each letter
list_of_words = IO.foreach("referencewords.txt")
letter_choice = gets.chomp
letter_choice = letter_choice.split(/,*/)

#make new blank array for possible words
final_word_array = []
list_of_words.each do |word|
    final_word_array.push(word) if letter_choice.include?(word)
end

#show possible words to the user
final_word_array.each do |word|
    puts word
end
```

When I run this code, I get nothing in my `final_word_array`. My question is, why am I not getting a list of possible words in my 'final_word_array'?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Check into the Ruby File class which extends IO, specifically File.open (http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/File.html#method-c-open) and then the each_line method inherited from IO.

Comment: Your call `letter_choice.split` is wrong. You need to use something like `letter_choice.split(/,\s*/)`, which splits on a comma followed by zero or more blank space characters. Your current regex breaks on zero or more commas, which gives results like: `letter_choice = "a, b, c, d"; letter_choice = letter_choice.split(/,*/)` => `["a", " ", "b", " ", "c", " ", "d"]`.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see what's happening.

Your `letter_choice` local variable ends up being an array of letters after you split it with the regex.

```
# assume input was "a, b, c, d"
letter_choice = "a, b, c, d"
letter_choice = letter_choice.split(/,*/) # => ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Later, you are looking for a whole work in a list of letters. Assume you have a word "bad" in your word list. You would be doing something like this:

```
if letter_choice.include?(word)
# would be
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'].include?("bad") # => false
```

So, the code is behaving correctly. I would suggest using `Set`s. Make `list_of_words` to hold an array of sets that are made out of letters in your words. Then just check if your letters are a [subset](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-subset-3F) of your the word.

```
word.subset?(letter_choice_set)
```

---

**Update:** Forgot to mention that this option would not account for repeating letters. Words like "badd" would also match, even if user inputs only one "d".

Comment: This is right about the main algorithmic problems (+1). I just wanted to mention that the `split` call is still wrong (see my [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36651803/checking-which-words-in-a-list-could-be-made-from-user-input-letters#comment60897536_36651803) above).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help:

```
list_of_words = IO.foreach("referencewords.txt")
letter_choice = gets.chomp.split(/,*/)

final_word_array = []
list_of_words.each do |word|
  letters_of_word = word.split('').uniq
  final_word_array.push(word) if (letters_of_word && letter_choice) == letters_of_word
end

#show possible words to the user
final_word_array.each do |word|
  puts word
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample list of words:

```
a = ["cat", "bat", "dog", "god", "rabbit"]
```

Conversion:

```
h = a.group_by{|s| s.each_char.sort}
# => {
#  ["a", "c", "t"]=>["cat"],
#  ["a", "b", "t"]=>["bat"],
#  ["d", "g", "o"]=>["dog", "god"],
#  ["a", "b", "b", "i", "r", "t"]=>["rabbit"]
#}
```

Sample user input:

```
s = "o,d,g\n"
```

Possible words:

```
h[s.chomp.split(",").sort] # => ["dog", "god"]
```

Comment: The user input is a "list of letters separated by commas". I presume that would be `"b,d,o,a,t,c\n"` in your example.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If some or all of the letters can be used for form words, you could do the following.

**Code**

```
words_by_letters = word_list.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k]=[] }) { |word, h|
  h[word.each_char.sort] << word }

def extract_words(words_by_letters, letters)
  (1..letters.size).flat_map do |n|
    letters.combination(n).map(&:sort).uniq.flat_map do |word_set|
      words_by_letters[word_set]
    end.compact
  end.reject(&:empty?)
end
```

**Examples**

```
word_list = ["a", "at", "cat", "bat", "do", "dog", "god", "act", "rot", "robot"]

words_by_letters = word_list.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k]=[] }) { |word, h|
  h[word.each_char.sort] << word }
  #=> {["a"]=>["a"],
  #    ["a", "t"]=>["at"],
  #    ["a", "c", "t"]=>["cat", "act"],
  #    ["a", "b", "t"]=>["bat"],
  #    ["d", "o"]=>["do"],
  #    ["d", "g", "o"]=>["dog", "god"],
  #    ["o", "r", "t"]=>["rot"],
  #    ["b", "o", "o", "r", "t"]=>["robot"]}

extract_words(words_by_letters, ['c', 'a', 't'])
  #=> ["a", "at", "cat", "act"] 

extract_words(words_by_letters, ['o', 'g', 'd'])
  #=> ["do", "dog", "god"] 

extract_words(words_by_letters, ['o', 'o', 't', 'r', 'b'])
  #=> ["rot", "robot"]
```